# Clearing Cookies from Browser using react-native-auth0's clearSession Method

Tags: react-native, react-native-auth0

I am currently developing a `React-Native` application using `react-native-auth0` for authentication. I am trying to clear the session and cookies when the user logs out.

I am using the clearSession method from `react-native-auth0` like so:

```js
    auth0.webAuth
     .clearSession({})
     .then(success => console.log('Session cleared'))
     .catch(error => console.log('Failed to clear session:', error));
```

This method clears the session as expected, but it does not clear the cookies from the browser. This means that when the user tries to log in again, they are not prompted for their credentials because the session cookies are still present in the browser.

I've also tried using the prompt: 'login' option in the authorize method to force the user to enter their credentials each time they log in, but this does not clear the cookies either.

Is there a way to clear the cookies from the browser using `react-native-auth0` or any other method in React Native? Any help would be greatly appreciated.